# node module.paths confusion

Tags: node.js, require

node module.paths confusion

Issue: required node modules do not use my global module.paths even though I add the global path to the array in my main.js application.

Example:

***mymain.js***

```
//global modules path
module.paths.push('C:\Users\xuser\AppData\Roaming\npm');
// finds ws in global modules path. Works!
wsmain=require('ws') 
// Now load a 3rd party module, which also requires('ws')
C = require('cmod.js');
```

***cmod.js***

```
ws=require('ws');  // fails to find global path
```

q: How do I make sure that module global is also passed on to the require modules. Is there a way to pass it as a parameter or something?

Comment: In this particular case, you can use `module.parent.require` combo ([the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_require_id)). If all the modules in question are under your control, it's possible to organize them in that way, but it might be a better idea to just require a folder. If not, I'd suggest playing with NODE_PATH instead.

Comment: i am looking for a way to pass the module.paths to any modules that are required() so they can use the paths to find their required modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a "global" path.  The node.js documentation suggests a default `require` takes place relative to the file requiring it, and searches for a `node_modules` directory up the directory chain.  From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders):

> For example, if the file at '/home/ry/projects/foo.js' called
> require('bar.js'), then node would look in the following locations, in
> this order:
>
> - /home/ry/projects/node_modules/bar.js
> - /home/ry/node_modules/bar.js
> - /home/node_modules/bar.js
> - /node_modules/bar.js

It looks like you can use `NODE_PATH` env var to give a list of places to look for modules:

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

Based on the documentation, the following might work:

`NODE_PATH=/path/to/node_modules/where/ws/lives node mymain.js`

Comment: at the moment the only thing that seems to work is to set the process.env.NODE_PATH to the globals path. It is still not what I was hoping for (I don't like adding items to the environment).